# Angularjs Changes in bootstrap css for date picker

Tags: angularjs, css, datepicker

I want to build custom build calendar in angularjs, I am using datepicker directive from angular ui bootstrap. I want to modify some of it's properties in css to use it in my application.
I am trying to make changes in css by using dev tool. but it is not changing.
Anyone can please help..

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: 1) you would have to change src files of datepicker for that.
2) you can use dev tools for that but as i said you would have to change source files.

Comment: you mean i have yo make changes in bootstrap.min.js?